# Exposed Sql Jetbrains, delete Column

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

how to delete Column in Exposed?

`object PlayerKits : Table() { val player = varchar("uuid", 16) override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(player) }`

//add Column - Working

`PlayerKits.integer("teste") SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(PlayerKits)`

//remove - Not Working

`val col = Column<Int>(PlayerKits, "test", IntegerColumnType()) col.dropStatement()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```kotlin
transaction {
  col.dropStatement().forEeach { statement ->
     exec(statement)
  }
}
```

Comment: thx it's working !